# Custom component namespace invokation

Tags: java, android, namespaces, custom-component

I am having problem with invoking a custom component in my Android projects in Eclipse. It seem that I do not understand how the namespace declarations belong together. I have checked several other threads here at SO, which at first seem to be related, but I cannot solve my problem with these:

- [android-custom-control-namespace-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745894/android-custom-control-namespace-issue)
- [how-to-pass-custom-component-parameters-in-java-and-xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495511/how-to-pass-custom-component-parameters-in-java-and-xml)
- [android-custom-widget-styles-how-to-put-them-into-a-namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453291/android-custom-widget-styles-how-to-put-them-into-a-namespace)

I have the following set-up (code is anonymized):

**/values/extra_attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="extraComponent">
        <attr name="count" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**/layout/extra_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/extra_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/extra_main" 
    />        
</merge>
```

**/com.site.package.extra/extra.java**

```
package com.site.package.extra;

... misc imports...

public class Extra extends FrameLayout
{
... misc code...
}
```

**/com.site.package/main.java** (start-up class)

```
package com.site.package;

... misc imports...

public class Main extends Activity
{
... misc code...
}
```

**/layout/main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  style="@style/main_style" 
  xmlns:extra="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.site.package" >

  <com.site.package.Extra
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    extra:count="3">
  </com.site.package.Extra>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem I face is; whatever I do, I cannot manage to invoke my custom component. The errors occur in may layout and I have tried to change the following items:

1. name space declaration

   - `xmlns:extra="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.site.package"`
   - `xmlns:extra="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.site.package.extra"`
   - `xmlns:extra="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/extra"`
2. component invokation

   - `<com.site.package.extraComponent />`
   - `<com.site.package.Extra.extraComponent />`
   - `<extraComponent />`
   - `<Extra.extraComponent />`
   - `<android.view.ext.extraComponent />`
3. attributes

   - `extra:count="3"`
   - `com.site.package.extra:count="3"`

In neither case I manage to get any help from intellisense so I am completely lost. I really do not understand how the namespaces are working here and how I should put the code to work.

**EDIT :**

I forgot to include my **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.site.package"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

  <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_logo"
    android:label="MyApp"
    android:name="MyApp" >

  <activity
    android:label="MyApp"
    android:name=".Main" >
    <intent-filter >
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom component is situated in the package `com.site.package.extra`(from the code you posted) so you could use it in the xml layout with:

```
<com.site.package.extra.Extra // ... other attributes
```

or with:

```
<view  class="com.site.package.extra.Extra"
     // ... other attributes />
```

The namespace for the custom attributes:

```
xmlns:extra="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.site.package"
```

and to use them:

```
extra:count="3"
```

Comment: This seem to be a step forward. I think I actually tried this in one of my many tests, but since I cannot get intellisense to work I was assuming this was wrong and did not test run. Still intellisense does not provide any help, so I assume that there is still something worng. Well, I went on to try to run in debugger/emulator and then I got an exception: **Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.site.package.extra.Extra**. Do you know why intellisense is not invoked and what situations can cause this error? The program does not give any errors or warnings in editor... :-(

Comment: @Ray'user1578904' The intellisense will not work for your custom views, this is where you go manually. In the logcat below the inflating exception on the line 13 there should be a cause for that exception(like class not found, NullPointerException in constructor etc). See what it tells you.

Comment: I get this cause with the exception: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.site.package.extra in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44e8d200**

Comment: I have learned a few things already. I was before confused about namespace belongings, and couldn't get into my head which namespace to use because I was assuming my custom attributes somehow needed to be linked to the component namespace. Also interesting to know that intellisense is not supposed to work here.

Comment: @Ray'user1578904' In the exception you posted the package + class name is `com.site.package.extra`(which is how you probably have it in the xml layout), shouldn't that be `com.site.package.extra.Extra`?

Comment: you are right, at the same moment I posted the detailed error message I noticed the error. It seem to work now, and I will mark the issue as solved.

Comment: May I add just one follow-up question? I can edit my layout xml in xml mode with no problem, but I was expecting to be able to render the result in the Graphical Layout. However, I get just a label with the class name and below I get an error "The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.site.package.extra.Extra (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse". Is this normal? The code is working fine once compiled.

Comment: @Ray'user1578904' Unfortunately I can't help you with that as I don't use the graphical editor that much. You could use that tip and implement the `isInEditMode` method for your `View` to return `true`.