# Android carousel View

Tags: android, android-layout

i just export  a package to make a carousel to my project in xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ListView 
        android:id="@+android:id/list1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        >
        <com.me.controls.Carousel
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:id="@+id/carousel"  
                pj:UseReflection="true"
                pj:Items="@array/entries" 
                pj:SelectedItem="0"
                android:animationDuration="200"
            />  
</LinearLayout>             
</LinearLayout>
```

when run it gives error:error Parsing XML: unbound prefix.
but i don't know the reason please any one help??

Comment: Try to write "android:orientation="vertical" " this line also for linearLayout which is inside of your listView..

Comment: Just realized, as i know you shouldn't use android:layout_width="fill_parent" with android:layout_weight="1".. try to set android:layout_width="0px" if you need to use weight.

Comment: my problem not in listView te list works good the error occure in <com.me.controls.carousel ......

Comment: The issue is caused by these "pj:UseReflection="true"
                pj:Items="@array/entries" 
                pj:SelectedItem="0"" attributes. You need to add a (valid) namespace for them - just as "android:" is declared in the start of your document.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8003730/1012284

Comment: i added it but it gave an error :no resource idintifir found for attribute Items & SelectedItem I already defined them in attr.xml in a values @Jens

Comment: @loleana you should probably update your question with the fixed layout and the attr.xml you've defined.

Answer (score 2):

//you created id for listview is wrong

```
android:id="@+android:id/list1"
```

try this below one

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Comment: the  problem not in the listView the list worked good but when i add the  <com.me.controls.Carousel
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:id="@+id/carousel"  
                pj:UseReflection="true"
                pj:Items="@array/entries" 
                pj:SelectedItem="0"
                android:animationDuration="200"
            />   the error happend

Answer (score 1):

You need to define name space here to use custom view's attributes.

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453291/android-custom-widget-styles-how-to-put-them-into-a-namespace).